# Move element into correct order based upon attribute value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying for the first time to use the data attibrute with jQuery, what id like to do is move an element to the correct order based upon the data-order attribute.

Im unsure how to find the correct value of the data-order attribute though as I keep recieveing 'undefined'?

an anybody see what im doing wrong? and also, is there a way to find the correct elemtn it should come after in the dom? so if the data-attribute for the current value is 5, then it should come after the attribute with the balue 4..

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

// Move the profile back to positton funciton
function dmoveProfile(){

    alert($(this).data("data-order"))

};

$('.box').click(function(){
    alert($(this).data("data-order"))
});

// move into position


});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fta6p/

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #1:**

[.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is used to Store arbitrary data associated with the matched elements. Use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) instead.

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("data-order"))
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fta6p/2/)

**Solution #2:**

*For Sorting the DOM elements in ascending order you can do like this:*

```
jQuery.fn.sortDomElements = (function() {
   return function(comparator) {
      return Array.prototype.sort.call(this, comparator).each(function(i) {
              this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
      });
    };
})();

$("section").children().sortDomElements(function(a,b){
    akey = $(a).attr("data-order");
    bkey = $(b).attr("data-order");
    if (akey == bkey) return 0;
    if (akey < bkey) return -1;
    if (akey > bkey) return 1;
})
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fta6p/8/)

*Note:* Your div `#5` is overlapped on Div `#1`

*You can see output of div normal, if you try `inspect element` you will or `viewpagesource` you will see the DOM elements are arranged in Ascending order*

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you have enough answers as to why your ordering function doesn't work right.

Sorting your elements with basic JS is better. If you're looking for a jquery solution you can find it here:

```
function sortBoxes(){
    for(var i=1; i<= $('.box').length; i++) {
        var $box = $('.box[data-order="'+i+'"]');
        $box.appendTo($('section'));
    }
};

$('.box').click(function(){
    // alert($(this).data("order"));
    sortBoxes();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Fta6p/7/

Answer (score 0):

[Updated fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/validide/Fta6p/4/)

Use the jQuery .data() method without the "data-" prefix, like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    // Move the profile back to positton funciton
    function dmoveProfile(){

        alert($(this).data("order"))

    };

    $('.box').click(function(){
        alert($(this).data("order"))
    });

    // move into position


});
```